# Ajax call completed event

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to know if there is any event that fires when an element get completed rendering. I have a div say with id A. Now I am creating and rendering that div with ajax and need to access elements inside div. How can I do it. Tried with $("#A").init(). It is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are updating your div with an ajax-call, a callback function can be added to the parameters. This callback function will be run once the ajax-call completes:

```
$("#A").load(url, parameters, function () {
    // access elements inside div here
});
```

Comment: I wil l check that on Monday. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback

load( url, data, callback )

why can't u start working with the div in the callback?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way is to put your manipulation in the callback of the load/ajax/post/etc AJAX call.  If you can't do that (for whatever reason), perhaps this the [ajaxComplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxComplete#callback) event is what you're after:

```
$("#msg").ajaxComplete(function(request, settings){
  $(this).append("<li>Request Complete.</li>");
});
```

Of course you have to detect that it's the right AJAX call that's completed but maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problem many times. I almost gave up till I went through detailed documentation of [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.

Normally by using .on() function we attach event handlers like following:

```
    $("#dataTable tbody tr").on("click",function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
```

But by delegated-events approach we may achieve same thing by:

```
    $("#dataTable tbody").on("click","tr",function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
```

Here, even if the table rows i.e tr elements get updated by ajax call, the above code will still remain attached it and would continue to perform intended actions.

I guess this solves your question.